# Word that refers to efforts by people of all religions to develop closer relationships and better understandings

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms, religion

I am looking for a word like *ecumenical*:

> Ecumenism refers to efforts by Christians of different Church traditions to develop closer relationships and better understandings. [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecumenism)

What I want is a word that means the same but encompasses all world religions instead of just Christian denominations.

I am convinced that the lack of such a word is at the root of so much of the world's conflict.  I expect I will have to coin a word which facilitates cooperation among the world's religions thus modeling the target behavior for their adherents.

I found: *latitudinarian*

> : not insisting on strict conformity to a particular doctrine or standard : tolerant; specifically : tolerant of variations in religious opinion or doctrine [*Merriam-Webster*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latitudinarian)

Tolerant is not sufficient.  I want a word that connotes active engagement.

Comment: Neologisms are off-topic on EL&U.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: “[Privileges - comment everywhere](/help/privileges/comment)”, “[Is SE enforcing ‘no answers in comments’?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10646/is-se-enforcing-no-answers-in-comments)”.

Comment: @user3293056 See note above.

Comment: @GlobalCharm Avoid using comments for a purpose other than asking the author for clarification, pointing out problems, or suggesting changes. Reports of moderator tool abuse are welcome, but should be posted to [chat] (informal, public), [meta] (formal, public), or the [Community Management Team Inbox](https://english.stackexchange.com/contact) (formal, private), as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that "universal religion" is often used in this context:

> Influenced by Eastern religions and marked by spiritualism, which was
>   fashionable at the end of the nineteenth century, Theosophy sought to
>   bring together religion and science and claimed to be ***a universal
>   religion***, one that went beyond sectarianism.

Andrew Wernick, on the "[secular religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_of_Humanity)" of Auguste Comte. Note, I have not read this book. You should try [this](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1057/9780230378919_1) article, but it's behind a paywall, I'm afraid!

If that's too much, then the phrase "[interfaith dialogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaith_dialogue)" is common, and included in some definitions of 'ecumenical'.

Comment: Thanks, from your link "interfaith dialogue", I got interreligious dialogue.  But from @Global Charm above i get the realization that i am not including agnostics; which seems to be a kind of secular religion.  It is difficult to imagine inclusive when some of the participants don't want to associate.  Catholic means all-encompassing as per Google dictionary.  Maybe that will have to do, unless someone proposes better.

Comment: i think 'inclusive' is often just an attitude, and it can be defined as not excluding. and what is wrong with 'faith' here, it seems exclusionary to avoid it @TruthReigns it seems to be the broader term, encompassing any strongly held "belief" and i don't think is being misapplied?

Comment: There does not seem to be consensus as which to use but from the link you provided, i saw that interfaith refers to Abrahamic religions.  In any case i am looking for a word that connotes more effort than just dialogue.